# Check if a graph is bipartite or not

Tags: java, graph

I have to write a program to check if a graph is bipartite or not. I have done it but it is failing at some test cases. I think it is happening because I'm not keeping the track of visited nodes. I'm including my code. Can anyone help in solving this?

```
static boolean isBipartite(int G[][],int src,int V)
{      
    int colorArr[] = new int[V];
    for (int i=0; i<V; ++i)
        colorArr[i] = -1;

    colorArr[src] = 1;

    LinkedList<Integer>q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    q.add(src);

    while (q.size() != 0)
    { 
        int u = q.poll();

        for (int v=0; v<V; ++v)
        {         
            if (G[u][v]==1 && colorArr[v]==-1)
            {            
                colorArr[v] = 1-colorArr[u];
                q.add(v);
            }

            else if (G[u][v]==1 && colorArr[v]==colorArr[u])
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add the tag for which programming language this is?

Comment: the function is written in java

Comment: Then why is it tagged [tag:c++]?

Comment: that happened by mistake